# ansible variables usage - ansible_hostname or {{ ansible_hostname }}

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am new to ansible. What is the correct to call ansible variables? Here are the 3 playbooks, playbook 1 uses "{{ ansible_hostname }}", however, playbook 2 and 3 uses "ansible_hostname" directly. What are the differences? Thanks!

Playbook 1:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Jinja2 template
      template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: "/tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}_template.out"
        trim_blocks: true
        mode: 0644
```

Playbook 2:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Ansible Jinja2 if
      debug:
        msg: >
             --== Ansible Jinja2 if statement ==--
 
             {# If the hostname is ubuntu-c, include a message -#}
             {% if ansible_hostname == "ubuntu-c" -%}
                   This is ubuntu-c
             {% endif %}
```

Playbook 3:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Exploring register
      command: hostname -s
      when: 
        - ansible_distribution == "CentOS" 
        - ansible_distribution_major_version | int >= 8
      register: command_register
```

Comment: Does [_Ansible uses Jinja2 templating to enable dynamic expressions and access to variables and facts. You can use templating with the template module._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) answer your question? Both are correct, whereby #2 is using more of [Jinja2 templating language](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#template-module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> playbook 1 uses "{{ ansible_hostname }}", however, playbook 2 uses "ansible_hostname"

That's not entirely correct. Both playbooks use the variable name `ansible_hostname` inside a Jinja templating context.

- In the first playbook, it's simple variable substitution, so we use the `{{ ... }}` markers.
- In the second playbook, it's being used in a control expression, so we use the `{% ... %}` markers.
- In the third playbook, you're looking at the clauses of a [`when` expression](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when). From the documentation:

  > The when clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces...

You can read more about Jinja syntax [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/).

Comment: Thanks! I have added another playbook 3, it uses ansible_distribution directly without {{ }}, I believe the reason is that playbook 3 uses it as control expression as well?

Comment: I've updated the answer for your third playbook.